# In PHP what's the best way of filtering out sets of words from plain text

Tags: php, regex, search, substring, preg-match

Say you have plain text input. Within that text you have key words to look for. Say 'cost', 'location' and 'materials' you want to filter out the words that come after these key words so you can store them later in DB under columns with those key words.

How would you do that? I was thinking of converting the string to an array then searching that and using the key value to work out the ranges of words between the key words. This is just an idea anyone got any better one?

Example input:

```
Cost £45 Materials glue, plastic, wood and nails Location Sale, Manchester North England.
```

Content the grouped like this in vars:

```
$cost = "£45";
$materials = "glue, plastic, wood and nails";
$location = "Sale, Manchester North England";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex for matching you values:

```
\s*\bCost\s+(?<cost>.+?)\s*\bMaterials\s+(?<material>.+?)\s*\bLocation\s+(?<location>.+)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/cK7eF7/1)

**Code:**

```
$re = '/\s*\bCost\s+(?<cost>.+?)\s*\bMaterials\s+(?<material>.+?)\s*\bLocation\s+(?<location>.+)/'; 

preg_match($re, $str, $matches);

print_r($matches);
```

You will get your matched values in `$matches` array with name of index indicating the values it matched.

Answer (score 1):

To obtain the text in between what a pattern matches, you can use [`preg_split`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.preg-split.php). In this case, I suggest matching any of your keywords, using [*word boundaries*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) (`\b`), which allows you to parse a text with keywords in no particular order.

Regex:

```
/\b(Cost|Materials|Location)\b/i
```

And to include the keywords in the result of [`preg_split`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.preg-split.php), we use the [`PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE` flag](http://php.net/manual/es/function.preg-split.php).

```php
preg_split($re, $str, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
```

The text before the first keyword match is also returned. We'll just use `array_shift()` to discard it.

#### Code:

```php
$re = '/\b(Cost|Materials|Location)\b/i'; 
$str = "<preceding text> Cost £45 Materials glue, plastic, wood and nails Location Sale, Manchester North England."; 

//$re matches keywords, but also captures them... PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE includes the captures in the result
$result = preg_split($re, $str, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);

//Remove preceding text
array_shift($result);
print_r($result);
```

#### Result

```php
Array
(
    [0] => Cost
    [1] =>  £45 
    [2] => Materials
    [3] =>  glue, plastic, wood and nails 
    [4] => Location
    [5] =>  Sale, Manchester North England.
)
```

[Run this code](http://rextester.com/GKSE54269)